# link_to passing query parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, link-to

Need to be able to generate the following URL string

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/cities?q%5Bprovince_id_eq%5D=1&commit=Filter&order=city_name_asc
```

how does this link_to need to be setup?

```
link_to(p.cities.count, admin_cities_path)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just pass the query parameters as a hash to the URL helper, e.g. Running the following commands in my console, I get the following hash:

```
url = "http://localhost:3000/admin/cities?q%5Bprovince_id_eq%5D=1&commit=Filter&order=city_name_asc"    
query = URI.parse(url).query
hash = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(query)
#=> { "q" => { "province_id_eq" => "1" }, "commit" => "Filter", "order" => "city_name_asc" }
```

Then you'd just do

```
admin_cities_url(hash)
```

To get back to the original URL.

Answer (score 1):

Probably [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) will help you, take a look after the "link_to can also produce links with anchors or query strings"

```
link_to(p.cities.count, admin_cities_path(q: { province_id_eq: 1 }, order: "city_name_asc"))
```